# Why do I have to "renew Touch ID purchases" all the time?

Tags: password, ios, iphone

I have an iPhone 5S, and I have automatic app updates disabled as I like to manage these myself. However, when I do, I have to enter my Apple ID password every time?

If I make new purchases, it seems to go through with the Touch ID; however, if I update an app I am forced to manually enter my password.

I have the 7.0.1 update and apple store purchases under the `General` => `Fingerprint` section in `Settings`, which is turned on.

I have searched the apple discussion forums and the common answer seems to be the update. It's not that.

So short question is, why do I have to actually "Confirm Apple ID password for  to renew Touch ID purchases" all the time?

How can I have it use TouchID as I have it set in the settings?

Comment: I can't really offer a solution, but from [this article](http://www.cultofmac.com/246572/iphone-5s-first-impressions-touch-id/), it seems that you aren't the only one having this issue. I guess that passwords have not been completely eliminated yet, so this behavior is intentional.

Comment: Updating an app should never require a password, let alone prompt the user to "renew Touch ID purchases" for every one.

Comment: @tubedogg, I couldn't agree more.

Comment: @sameetandpotatoes, that's only one of two blog posts/articles I found on Google. Both say pretty much the same thing. I'm guessing because it's all so new and by default automatic app updates are in fact `automatic` that not too many people have come across this.

Comment: What does all the time mean? Constantly, once per update, once per check, 2.3 times a day on average? Twice a month?

Comment: @bmike, more like twice a day. There is a known feature that the first logon after power-up required your passcode. But I also get it when just logging in normally now too (not all the time, but at least once a day, if not more). I have right now a screen on my phone with the passcode digits with text: `Enter Passcode to enable Touch ID`

Comment: I got iphone 5, I didn't have to type password confirm when updating app. Maybe my country app store or my icloud account is slightly different from yours.

Comment: @Madivad Do you have the issue still with 7.0.4?

Comment: @AndrewU. Less frequently than I use to, but it does still happen. I am aware of the need when first powering up, and the updates work differently now (compared to 7.0.1), but it does still occur.

Answer (score 1):

Security, if someone else puts his finger into touch ID, he could purchase everything. Or if someone logs in with his apple id on your phone, you could just buy things without knowing his password.

Touch ID isn't linked to your Apple ID, but to your phone

Answer (score -5):

Prior to the launch of the iPhone 5s, I went on record on the iMore Show with my one desire for the then much rumored fingerprint sensor. If it arrived and didn't allow me to buy apps and content from iTunes by touching my finger to it, then I wasn't that interested. Delight then, that Apple took the stage, announced Touch ID, and that we could use it to buy things. Delight, quickly followed by epic frustration.

Why frustration? Because I still find myself entering my Apple ID password at present twice a day, minimum. I'm referring to a message which pops up just after hitting the install button on a new app from the App Store. It says;

Confirm Apple ID Password for "........." to Renew Touch ID Purchases

The only instance I've come across elsewhere on the iPhone 5s that specifically requests passcode input over Touch ID is when you restart the device. That's understandable, but it also doesn't require entering a 20+ character password. I have a long and complex Apple ID password – as should everyone else – which is precisely why I was so excited when Apple announced Touch ID support for the stores. I'm lazy. And entering a 20+ character password every time you want to download an app gets tiresome.